# C++: printing unicode characters

Tags: c++, unicode

I wrote a simple program to print a unicode smile emoji.  Unfortunately, something else is printed.  Does anyone know what the problem with this code is?  Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string str = u8"\u1F600";

    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and output:

```
g++ -pedantic -Wall test109.cc && ./a.out
ὠ0
```

Comment: Or, if your compiler allows it, just use the emoji itself: `u8""`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Emacs has M-x insert-char, which I can add it, however it is displayed a box with the Unicode number in Emacs.  It is printed correctly in my terminal application using Mac's Terminal.app outside of Emacs.  Figure Emacs would have full Unicode support by now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\u` [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) have the format `\u####` (i.e. exactly 4 hex digits). You need `\U########`:

```
auto str = u8"\U0001F600";
```

Or, encoding the UTF8 bytes separately:

```
auto str2 = u8"\xf0\x9f\x98\x80";
```

That works.

Comment: That only works if your console properly interprets UTF-8.  Probably does on Linux but not on Windows.

Comment: @MarkRansom I mean, sure.

Comment: Now that the question has been updated with example output, I can see that the console is showing [ὠ (U+1F60 GREEK SMALL LETTER OMEGA WITH PSILI)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f60/index.htm) so I guess it's not an issue.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, beccause `"\u1F600"` is parsed as two separate characters `\u1F60` (U+1F60) and `0` (U+0030), because `\u` has a max of 4 hex digits.

Comment: @RemyLebeau absolutely.  That's evidence both that this answer is correct, and the OP's console can handle UTF-8.

Comment: @KonradRudolph First part understood. Where are you getting the hex str2 from?

Comment: @notaorb You can compute it from the code point by applying the UTF-8 encoding rules. But there’s no need for that, since it’s easily found online: many database websites for Unicode characters (e.g. fileformat.info) contain the UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 5):

The `\u` escape sequence is limited to 4 hex digits max, so `"\u1F600"` is parsed as two separate characters `\u1F60` (`ὠ`) and `0`, which is exactly what you are seeing in your console output.

Codepoint [U+1F60 GREEK SMALL LETTER OMEGA WITH PSILI](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f60/index.htm) is very different than codepoint [U+1F600 GRINNING FACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f600/index.htm).

For what you are trying, you need to use the `\U` escape instead, which allows up to 8 hex digits:

```cpp
string str = u8"\U0001F600";
```

Alternatively, you can use one of these instead:

```cpp
string str = u8"\xF0\x9F\x98\x80"; // UTF-8 codeunits in hex format
```

```cpp
string str = u8"\360\237\230\200"; // UTF-8 codeunits in octal format
```

```cpp
string str = u8""; // if your compiler/editor allows this
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following which works for you.

```
string str = "\u263A"; //        -->  ☺

//string str = u8"\xe2\x98\xba"; -->  ☺

//string str = u8"\U0001F600";   --> 

//string str = u8"";           --> 

//string str = "\342\230\272"    -->  ☺

cout << str << endl;
```

Comment: `"\u263A"` will not work for codepoint U+1F600. Neither will `u8"\xe2\x98\xba"` and `"\342\230\272"`.  Those are all for codepoint U+263A instead. The correct UTF-8 sequence for U+1F600 is `"\xF0\x9F\x98\x80"`

Comment: These are not all the same character.

Comment: @KonradRudolph All are one or other type of smileys

Comment: @Abhishek But they are not the SAME smiley.  [U+1F600](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f600/index.htm) is "GRINNING FACE".  [U+263A](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263A/index.htm) is "WHITE SMILING FACE".  Very different smileys

Comment: I know but that doesn’t help OP, does it? You even say that “the first [piece of code] is recommended” but, as Remy correctly said, that won’t work for the specific emoji which OP wants.

Comment: Well, as per the question, OP wants to print smiley emoji. He didn't mention which kind of..

Comment: @Abhishek It is very evident in the OP's question that U+1F600 is wanted. Provide proper examples for THAT smiley, and then I will be happy to upvote your answer. Until then, I have downvoted it since it is giving the OP bad advice.